# Xamarin Android app - Problems adding async/await to an API call to improve performance

Tags: c#, android-asynctask, xamarin.android

I found that my Xamarin Android app is running slowly so I added some async/await code to improve the performance. I wanted to excluded my API calls from the UI thread. I thought this would be a perfect opportunity to use async/await.  So, I added async to the signature of the function and wrapped Task around my return value type.  Then I updated the RestSharp GET call with "await client.ExecuteTaskAsync."  Once I did this I found I needed to update my call to the GetCustInfo function.  I simply needed to add .Result to the end of the call and it showed no errors.  The problem is it hangs on the call to GetCustInfo and just doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    public async Task<List<CustInfo>> GetCustInfo(string strBranchNumber, string dblCurrentXCoordinate, string dblCurrentYCoordinate)
    {
        if (this.strBearerToken == string.Empty)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No Bearer Token Found");
        }

        try
        {
            var restUrl = this.strCustomerInfoAPIURL;
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(restUrl, string.Empty));

            var client = new RestClient(uri);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + this.strBearerToken);
            request.AddParameter("intBranchNumber", strBranchNumber);
            request.AddParameter("intZipCode", this.strZipCode);
            request.AddParameter("intCustomerType", this.strCustomerType);
            request.AddParameter("intMinTotalAmount", this.strMinRevenue);
            request.AddParameter("dblCurrentXCoordinate", dblCurrentXCoordinate);
            request.AddParameter("dblCurrentYCoordinate", dblCurrentYCoordinate);
            request.AddParameter("bolGetLocation", true);

            var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);                
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustInfo>>(response.Content).OrderBy(x => x.ApproxDistance).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So what is happening is when I call the async/await function from my OnCreate it just stops when I try to call customer.GetCustomerInfo().

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
      ....

            this.tableItems = customer.GetCustInfo(
                "xxxxxxx",
                this.currentLocation.Latitude.ToString(),
                this.currentLocation.Longitude.ToString()).Result;
             this.listView.Adapter = new ListOfLocationAdapter(this, this.tableItems);

    }
```

Comment: OnCreate itself is on the UI thread of the action that you're entering, and not async, and you are not awaiting the call to GetCustInfo. so it behaves like a blocking call. use a different event in the UI lifecycle to trigger it, and call it using the `await` syntax.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?  Won't all events in the UI lifecycle be part of the UI thread?

Comment: I did some research and found that I should add my call to custinfo in the OnStart call that is within the lifecycle.  It is working.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Change the call to

```
this.tableItems = await customer.GetCustInfo(..
```

and let us know..
In the next line you are using the result from the not-awaited call, it obviously would hangs, crash whatever:

```
this.listView.Adapter = new ListOfLocationAdapter(this, **this.tableItems**); //this.tableItems is just empty
```

Comment: just create an async func with the full content of your OnCreate and call it without await, now that would speed it up and do what you want.